# Why can i use integers inside CGSizeMake and CGRectMake?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I use integers all the time in these two commands. It works fine and I suspect it's common to do this.

But technically, I believe they require CG Floats, not integers.

Why does it work, and it is wrong to do this? If so, how to easily convert an `int` into a `cg float` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes an `int` can be implicitly converted to a `float` (i.e. `CGFloat`). Which means that, if you call `CGSizeMake(40, 50)`, the C compiler can recognize that a `float` is required and convert the generated code to `CGSizeMake(40.0f, 50.0f)` automatically.